# getting Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#

how to deserialize data  getting error -

> "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property."

```
 var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.RawDatas);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

Comment: Check Web config  <configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>